# How do I include modules inside a main module?

Tags: fortran

In an attempt to simplify my code, I decided to create a module within another in the following fashion:

```
   module A
    contains                                                                                                                         
        module B
        real*8, parameter ::pi=3.14159
        end module B
   end module A


   program test
   use A
   write(*,*)pi
   end
```

This did not work. What are some of the strategies to simplify a module?

Comment: That (as your compiler tells you) isn't valid.  But what is it you want the "contained" module to do?  There are such things as _submodules_, but that is likely not what you are after.  If you just want to use `A` and get access to things from `B` then `module A;use B; end module A` works quite happily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is like this:

```
module B
    implicit none
    real, parameter :: pi = 3.14159
end module B

module A
    use B
    implicit none
end module A

program main
    use A
    implicit none
    print*, pi
end program main
```